# Select an inner button element using parent element's class

Tags: html, css, sass

Can you tell me how can I select an inner button element using parent element's class?

*.html*

```
    <m-spinner-button [options]="spinner" (click)="submit()" 
         class="accent">Recupera Password</m-spinner-button>
```

I have tried this. But it is not working. Any clue?

```
m-spinner-button .accent>button {
    background-color: #669adf !important;
}
```

Runtime:

[image]

Comment: remove the space `m-spinner-button.accent>button`

Comment: Yep, Thanks a lot @TemaniAfif